# How to perform lm.ridge summary?

Tags: r, regression, lm, summary

I wonder is there a way to output summary for ridge regression in R?
It is a result of `lm.ridge{MASS}` function.

For standard linear model you just do `summary(lm_model)` but what about ridge regression model?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just added a method that summarizes (or more precisely, [tidies](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf)) `"ridgelm"` objects to my [broom](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom) package. This takes the form of two S3 generics: `tidy` and `glance`. You can install it with `devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/broom")` (though you'll need to install `devtools` first).

As an example, let's set up a ridge regression:

```
library(MASS)
names(longley)[1] <- "y"
fit <- lm.ridge(y ~ ., longley, lambda = seq(0.001, .05, .001))
```

The `tidy` function provides a data frame that shows each combination of lambda and the estimated term:

```
library(broom)
td <- tidy(fit)
head(td)
##   lambda    GCV term estimate
## 1  0.001 0.1240  GNP    23.02
## 2  0.002 0.1217  GNP    21.27
## 3  0.003 0.1205  GNP    19.88
## 4  0.004 0.1199  GNP    18.75
## 5  0.005 0.1196  GNP    17.80
## 6  0.006 0.1196  GNP    16.99
```

While the `glance` function creates a one-row summary, particularly the choices of lambda by various methods:

```
g <- glance(fit)
g
##       kHKB     kLW lambdaGCV
## 1 0.006837 0.05267     0.006
```

This is useful because it makes it easy to plot and explore the data yourself rather than relying on MASS's plotters:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(td, aes(lambda, estimate, color = term)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

```
# plot of GCV versus lambda
ggplot(td, aes(lambda, GCV)) + geom_line() +
    geom_vline(xintercept = g$lambdaGCV, col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]

For more on these methods, see `?ridgelm_tidiers`, or see the package's vignettes for more about the `tidy` and `glance` methods in general.

Comment: Instead of glance You can use builtin function 'select' - it works the same. The ggplot function works the same as regular plot.lmridge (but of course looks more pritty).

Comment: @MarcinKosinski: `select` doesn't work the same way because it *prints* the selected values rather than returning them (so there's no way to save them, extract them, combine them, or add them to a graph, for example). `plot.ridgelm` produces a similar graph, but it's worth noting that it doesn't come with a legend, or a way to choose the colors. (Actually since the `plot.ridgelm` doesn't pass along its `...` to `matplot`, you have limited ability to customize it at all).

Comment: Ok I get it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `summary` method for the `ridgelm` class:

```
> methods(class = 'ridgelm')
[1] coef.ridgelm*   plot.ridgelm*   print.ridgelm*  select.ridgelm*
```

What should this summary return? 
You can extract all the information you need from the ridgelm-object.

However, you also could write your own summary methods for your purposes  (check the code for `summary.lm()` for a start).
If you're happy with it, you could send it to the maintainers of MASS.

Comment: You really think they would care and publish this function in their package?

Comment: You might get an interesting reply. Generally Prof Ripley will put in support functions when he deems them appropriate, so there may be reasons that he did not.

Answer (score 1):

you can use my `lmridge` package from CRAN.

Comment: I would appreciate extending the answer with a short use case and probably the literature I can refer to! Thanks in advance.